# My php script output a json array that starts as [[],

Tags: php, json

I have this php script which should output a json array, it does that  but my json array start with [[], why this two additional square brackets [] ?

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "mydb";
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
    $result = mysql_query("select * from mydb.mytable" ) 

     or die(mysql_error());  

    //create an array
    $emparray[] = array();
    while($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }
    $object =   $emparray;
    echo json_encode($object) ;
```

Comment: `$emparray[] = array();` Here you say add an array as first element to the array (which gets implicit created here) `$emparray`. ( Change it to: `$emparray = array();`)

Comment: change this one - `$emparray[] = array();` in to `$emparray = array();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to assign `$emparray[]` with an `array` again.

You can try the below one -

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "mydb";
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
$result = mysql_query("select * from mydb.mytable" ) 

 or die(mysql_error());  

//create an array
//$emparray[] = array(); change this one below one
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
// no need to create additional variable
//$object =   $emparray;
echo json_encode($emparray) ;
```